# How to check display (none/block) of a div in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, focus, onmouseup

I am using this,

```
$("#loginanchor1").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#signin_menu1").slideDown("slow");
});
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).parent("a.loginanchor1").length == 0) {
        //$(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
        $("#signin_menu1").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Everything works fine but what happens is when the `signin_menu1` is displayed block and i click my mouse button inside the div the div slidesup... I want mouseup function to be prevented  when the `signin_menu1` is displayed block. So i thought of changing the condition like,

`if(($(e.target).parent("a.loginanchor1").length==0) &&( //check the display of the div)`

Now how to check the display?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

try

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    var $parent = $(e.target).parent("a.loginanchor1");
    if ($parent.length == 0 && !$("#signin_menu1").is(':visible')) {
        //$(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
        $("#signin_menu1").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

I'm confused with the problem, but `$("#signin_menu1").is(':visible')` would check if the div is visible (display:block).

**added notes:**

you may try to check if the `$(e.target)` is the `signin_menu1` or the is inside `signin_menu1`. do it like this,

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).is('#signin_menu1') || $(e.target).closest('#signin_menu1').length > 0) { return ; } // do nothing on mouseup
    var $parent = $(e.target).parent("a.loginanchor1");
    if ($parent.length == 0) {
        //$(".signin").removeClass("menu-open");
        $("#signin_menu1").slideUp("slow");
    }
});
```

Comment: it works but the div doesn't slide up when i click outside the div

Comment: i want to prevent mouseup event inside the div

Comment: Please note that the `:visible` selector does not take effect if the parent element is `display: none`. So even if the element you check with `is(':visible')` has the CSS property `display: block / inline / ...` this selector won't fetch it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use jquery's [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) for this.